# Logic within 2 foreach statements

Tags: php

The following code is looping through two arrays, `$this->userKeyword` and `$this->userAllergens`.

```
foreach($this->userKeyword as $keyword){
    foreach($this->userAllergens as $allergens){
        if($keyword['keywordid'] != $allergens['keywordid']){
            ?>
            <label><?php echo $keyword['name'];?></label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $keyword['name'];?>" value="<?php echo $keyword['keywordid'];?>" /><br />
            <?php
        }
    }
}
```

If the first array contains, '1', '2', '3', '4' and the second array contains '3' and '4', at the moment when inside the second loop and on the iteration that contains '3', it will display '1', '2' and '4' and then when on the iteration that contains '4' will display '1', '2' and '3'.

My problem is that I need to alter the code so it only displays when a value isn't inside both arrays.

So here, I want '1' and '2' to display but not '3' and '4'.

Any advice? Cheers!

Comment: If I understand you right, try your output inside the first but outside the second foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to:

```
foreach($this->userKeyword as $keyword){
    if(!(in_array($keyword, $this->userAllergens, true)) {
        echo "$keyword";
    }
}
```

You would use the `in_array` function.  Be careful as the boolean flag sets whether or not you are doing a strict comparison and could lead to misleading results.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: My arrays contains IDs so a strict comparison wouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Possibly, but I just wanted to warn you about it due to PHP's type casting for comparisons. (i.e. 1 == true)

Answer (score 1):

Use array_diff, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php . You can also use in_array() though, array_diff is better

Comment: Seems like the exact function I had in mind, just never came across it before. Could you provide a simple code example for my arrays? I've tried to implement it but getting errors!

Comment: <?php
$array1 = array('1','2','3','4');
$array2 = array('2','3','5');
$diff_arr = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($diff_arr); //output Array ( [0] => 1 [3] => 4 )
?>

Comment: I missed something to write.